# Exception in a Query

Tags: sql, excel

can anyone tell me why this query throws an error "No value given for one or more required parameters."

`Select Status from [Viewer$] WHERE  SlNo-Viewer < 4`  ... I'm trying to query an excel file and this query is not working with that....Please help....

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the query, not **how** you are performing the query? i.e. the C# code around it

Comment: Yes i think...because the query is working fine when i'm searching for a text.

Comment: So why did you tag it `C#`? Please remove the tag if it's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: I'm using the query with C# code that's why i tagged it with C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SlNo-Viewer` is name of a single field, the *minus* character in the field name is interpreted as the minus operator and it's trying to subtract field called `Viewer` from field called `Slno`.

Try this instead:

```
Select [Status] from [Viewer$] WHERE [SlNo-Viewer] < 4
```